# How to return focus to editor in VS Code macro sending Python text to Debug Console?

Tags: python, macros, visual-studio-code

I have tried to key-bind a macro to send python text to the Debug Console and return focus to the editor in Visual Studio Code. This is what I have tried:

- Installed the [vscode-python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension
- Installed the [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros) extension

`settings.json`:

```
{
    "macros": {
        "selectionToReplAndReturnToEditor": [
            "editor.debug.action.selectionToRepl",
            "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup"
        ]
    }
}
```

`keybindings.json`:

```
[
    {
        "key": "alt+f9",
        "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
    },
    {
        "key": "alt+f10",
        "command": "workbench.debug.action.focusRepl",
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+enter",
        "command": "macros.selectionToReplAndReturnToEditor",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection && editorLangId == 'python' && inDebugMode"
    }
]
```

Now, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> does execute text in the Debug Console, but does not return focus to the editor. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> does that, but of course, I would like to bind a single key. Am I doing something wrong? Do I need some wait time in the macro? How can I achieve that?

Comment: I have the same question. did you find an answer since that time?

Comment: @kobi7 see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, using a different extension:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [ // requires vscode:extension/ryuta46.multi-command
    { // ctrl+enter, editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection && editorLangId == 'python' && inDebugMode
        "command": "multiCommand.selectionToReplAndReturnToEditor",
        "sequence": [
            "editor.debug.action.selectionToRepl",
            "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
        ]
    },
}
```

Answer (score 5):

@bers answer is a God-send. here is the full solution.

There are a few things that we need to do here:

1. to send stuff to the debugger's integrated REPL, you need the action called `editor.debug.action.selectionToRepl`.
2. then you need to figure out how to return focus to the active editor. This is where the multi-command extension comes in.
3. Finally, you need to condition your keybinding, so that this only gets activated when debugMode is on.

in `keybindings.json`

```
  {
    "key": "cmd+enter",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText",
    "when": "editorHasSelection && editorTextFocus && !inDebugMode"
  },

  {
    "key": "cmd+enter",
    // This needs to be the command you define above.
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { "command": "multiCommand.selectionToReplAndReturnToEditor" },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection && editorLangId == 'python' && inDebugMode" 
  },
```

In `settings.json`

```
"multiCommand.commands": [ // requires vscode:extension/ryuta46.multi-command
    { // ctrl+enter, editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection && editorLangId == 'python' && inDebugMode
      "command": "multiCommand.selectionToReplAndReturnToEditor",
      "sequence": [
        "editor.debug.action.selectionToRepl",
        "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
      ]
    },
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could anyone explain why this is not default built-in functionality of vscode?

Comment: Would be great if there is a way to improve it, where it sends the whole current line of the cursus to REPL when no text is selected.

Comment: When I hit ctrl+enter, I see "command 'extension.executeAREPLBlock' not found".